# Detect disabled attribute changed with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, controls, state

I have a html control, and need to detect when it's disabled state changes.

I tried:

```
cb.on("change", function() {
    if(cb.is(":disabled")) {
        // the control is disabled
    } else {
        // it's enabled
    }
});
```

This does not seem to work...is there another trick for detecting this change?

Comment: `if ( cb.prop("disabled") ) { ... }`, and changing an attribute does not trigger a change event, and neither does changing the value with JS.

Comment: You should fire an event manually when you change the state, and listen to _that_ event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled controls cannot change state via user interaction - only through code.

I don't think a change event is triggered when "disabled" changes properties either. All you can really do is poll the "disabled" property.

One thing for sure: if the change event fires, the control is NOT disabled.

Comment: https://aleen42.github.io/PersonalWiki/qa/detect_disabled_change.html